# For loop in batch programming

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have a set of files in a directory like below:

```
File-MyFile.txt
File-AnotherFile.txt
File-ThirdFile.txt
```

I want to rename all files like below:

```
MyFile.txt
AnotherFile.txt
ThirdFile.txt
```

How can I use a `for` loop to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris shows the best way to do it.  I think this might come close to what you asked for, though I didn't test it:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.txt') do call :dorename %%a
goto :eof

:dorename
set oldfile=%1
set newfile=%oldfile:File-=%
rename %oldfile% %newfile%
```

Comment: Ok, still not perfect but it does what you want it to do. YMMV.

Comment: `newfile=%oldfile:File-=%` can also be `newfile=%oldfile:~5%`

Comment: Just for completeness (this version is a bit more readable), you can use `*.txt` instead of `dir /b *.txt` and `%%~nxa` instead of `%%a`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a for loop:

> ```
> rename File- "" File-*.txt
> ```

Comment: Not working for me. Showing "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: Sorry, must have overlooked the dos-batch tag. This is for unix rename.