# edit filename using command prompt

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, cmd

I have a number of files in a folder, by mistaken in some of files I enter the wrong name
for example :

filename like : `abcefxyz.txt` while I suppose to enter `abcdevwxyz.txt`
that is I simply want to replace `ef` string in filename with `devw` 
how can I do this using command prompt?
please help...

```
  EDITED
```

I have a thousands of files whose name like : `SomethingLongString_OutdoorGames_DateTime.txt`
(which I suppose to enter) but

Accidently in some of files, may be hundreds or thousands in number, I have enter `SomethingLongString_IndoorGame_DateTime.txt`

I simply want to replace `IndoorGame` string in filename with `OutdoorGame`string (precisely saying).

Here `SomethingLongString` and `DateTime` strings in filename is different for different file.

I think this example is more helpful to understand my problem...

Answer (score 1):

on windows use

I dont know how to replace some chars with others,but u can rename [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197755/for-loop-in-batch-programming)

`dirpath> ren abcefxyz.txt abcdevwxyz.txt`

Comment: this is done for 2-3 file but I have number of such files and above is just an example, in real filename is very long and its very difficult for me to rename all such files

Comment: then u learn how to write a for loop in batch ,little batch programming u learn .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197755/for-loop-in-batch-programming

Comment: this helps to add or remove prefix and suffix from a filename not helpful to edit in somewhere middle of filename

Comment: that I already told,if u hav such dynamic requirement look for regular expressions in batch programming

Comment: @manish what have u tried?,edit ur question specifying requirement

Comment: I only able to replace the strings of same length, but in my case character length is different

Comment: @Manish probably u can devide ur solution into 2 or more depending on the requirement.devide and conquer

Answer (score 0):

DUNNO.. if they are all TXT files then isolate them in a folder.
From there use Advanced Renamer to a file with NO extension
this way you can use 26 letters to rename the bunch.

CMD use would be Ren A* A (1,2,3,4 etc)
or XCOPY a* A using an older computer..

in a batch you could use for @ (filename) do (ren) statements
Would this help?